# Binary search ("bisect") tool

Tags: code-golf

Implement the [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) as used to identify the source code revision that breaks a computer software program. Your tool should take two arguments specifying the earliest and latest numbered revision to search (both positive integers), and you have two options for making comparisons:

1. Execute the shell command `./test N`, where *N* is the revision number. If the test passes (*i.e.* the revision is good), it will return exit code 0.
2. Call the function `test(N)`, which will return `true` if the test passes, `false` otherwise.

Standard output must be the number of the first bad revision, and try to make your tool's source code as short as possible. Enjoy!

Comment: Just some clarification, do you want a script or just a function?

Comment: @Nemo157: A complete script. I include the `test(N)` function option primarily for fairness to those programming languages with no standard way to execute shell commands, such as JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ruby - <strike>92 82 62</strike> 60 characters

Iterative is way shorter, but nowhere near as cool as tail recursive.

```
l,h=$*.map &:to_i
test(m=(l+h)/2)?l=m+1:h=m-1 while l<=h
p l
```

The old tail recursive method for reference

```
b=proc{|l,h|h<l ?l:(m=(l+h)/2;test(m)?l=m+1:h=m-1;redo)}
puts b[*$*.map(&:to_i)]
```

#### Testing script

Uses a little magic to inject the `test` function and runs a file consisting of purely the above code.

```
low = Random.rand(100)
mid = low + Random.rand(1e25)
high = mid + Random.rand(1e50)

File.open('./bisect-test-method.rb','w') do |file|
  file << "def test(value)
             value < #{mid}
           end
          "
end

puts "Using input:"
puts "  low=#{low}"
puts "  high=#{high}"
puts "  first_bad=#{mid}"
puts "Output: #{`ruby -r ./bisect-test-method golf-bisect.rb #{low} #{high}`}"
```

Output:

```
Using input:
  low=4
  high=75343785543465286986587973836706907796015092187720
  first_bad=5013102893257647460384884
Output: 5013102893257647460384884
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 64 chars

This one is recursive, so will overflow the stack for really large input

```py
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
 B=lambda L,H:H>L+1 and B(*[L,L/2+H/2,H][test(L/2+H/2):][:2])or H
```

test run

```py
def test(n):
    print "testing ", n
    return n<66

L,H=10,1000


B=lambda L,H:H>L+1 and B(*[L,L/2+H/2,H][test(L/2+H/2):][:2])or H

print B(L,H)
```

outputs

```py
testing  505
testing  257
testing  133
testing  71
testing  40
testing  55
testing  62
testing  66
testing  64
testing  65
66
```

Comment: Should print 66, not 65 (return H, not L).

Comment: @Keith, ok changed that

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 77 chars

Abusing the python bisect module. L is the low value, H is the high value

```
class B:__getitem__=lambda s,n:test(n)
import bisect as b
b.bisect(B(),0,L,H)
```

here is a test run

```
def test(n):
    print "testing ", n
    return n>66
L,H=10,1000

class B:__getitem__=lambda s,n:test(n)
import bisect as b
b.bisect(B(),0,L,H)
```

outputs

```
testing  505
testing  257
testing  133
testing  71
testing  40
testing  56
testing  64
testing  68
testing  66
testing  67
```

Explanation:

Here is how bisect is defined. Basically it expects a list and decides whether to bisect up or down based on the value it finds by looking at `a[mid]`. This calls `__getitem__` on `a`, which instead of being a list, is a class that I have defined myself.

```
def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e <= x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e > x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just after the rightmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo

bisect=bisect_right
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 70 chars

```
def B(L,H):
 while L+1<H:M=L+H;L,H=[L,M/2,H][test(M/2):][:2]
 return L
```

test run

```
def test(n):
    print "testing ", n
    return n<66
L,H=10,1000

def B(L,H):
 while L+1<H:M=L+H;L,H=[L,M/2,H][test(M/2):][:2]
 return L

print B(L,H)
```

outputs

```
testing  505
testing  257
testing  133
testing  71
testing  40
testing  55
testing  63
testing  67
testing  65
testing  66
65
```